Can't safely eject SCSI disk drives
I’m working on implementing a safe eject function in C# that utilizes imports from C++ through the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace.
While the function works as expected for USB Data storage devices, it fails with SCSI Devices.
I’ve noticed that these larger drives can only be ejected using the built-in “Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media” utility, which doesn’t seem to have a corresponding API or allow passing arguments.
Is there a way to programmatically enable safe ejection for larger flash drives?
Edit - I actually need a function for ejecting SCSI Devices, When I call DeviceIOControl Function with arguments such as IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA & IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL fails too
In addition, I saw that my SCSI devices policy is defined as better performance by default, and it seems that I need to changed their policy to quick removal to enable eject outside the win10/11 special app. But it can't enable me to change to policy according to "Device Settings", what should I do?
code snippet :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace USBRemoval
{
    internal class USBMagic
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
        uint dwShareMode,
        IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
        uint dwCreationDisposition,
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
            IntPtr hDevice,
            uint dwIoControlCode,
            IntPtr lpInBuffer,
            uint nInBufferSize,
            IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
            uint nOutBufferSize,
            out uint lpBytesReturned,
            IntPtr lpOverlapped
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
            IntPtr hDevice,
            uint dwIoControlCode,
            byte[] lpInBuffer,
            uint nInBufferSize,
            IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
            uint nOutBufferSize,
            out uint lpBytesReturned,
            IntPtr lpOverlapped
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        private IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

        const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
        const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;
        const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;
        const int FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME = 0x00090018;
        const int FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME = 0x00090020;
        const int IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA = 0x2D4808;
        const int IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL = 0x002D4804;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the USBEject class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="driveLetter">This should be the drive letter. Format: F:/, C:/..</param>

        public static IntPtr USBEject(string driveLetter)
        {
            string filename = @"\\.\" + driveLetter[0] + ":";
            return CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, 0x3, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        public static bool Eject(IntPtr handle)
        {
            bool result = false;

            if (LockVolume(handle) && DismountVolume(handle))
            {
                PreventRemovalOfVolume(handle, false);
                result = AutoEjectVolume(handle);
            }
            CloseHandle(handle);
            return result;
        }

        private static bool LockVolume(IntPtr handle)
        {
            uint byteReturned;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out byteReturned, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static bool PreventRemovalOfVolume(IntPtr handle, bool prevent)
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1];
            uint retVal;

            buf[0] = (prevent) ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
            return DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL, buf, 1, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out retVal, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private static bool DismountVolume(IntPtr handle)
        {
            uint byteReturned;
            return DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out byteReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private static bool AutoEjectVolume(IntPtr handle)
        {
            uint byteReturned;
            return DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out byteReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private bool CloseVolume(IntPtr handle)
        {
            return CloseHandle(handle);
        }


First step is to find out what actually makes the difference in observed behavior (which is almost certainly not merely size.... for example, check if you are dealing with "USB Mass Storage" vs "USB-attached-SCSI").  There's a whole bunch of information in Device Manager that may help you find the pattern.

in addition to Ben Voigt, also check if it's depending on the file system. FAT32 / NTFS

I have edited the question according the last findings
